# Node.js PDFkit causes ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, fs, pdfkit

this is really frustrating problem. I use node.js and pdfkit to generate invoice for customer of online shop.

```
exports.postOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
...

const order = new Order({
...
});

...

generateInvoice(order, invoicePath);
console.log('after invoice generated');
...
```

At first, everything worked fine, but after nothing changed it just one day stopped working. Somewhere inside generateInvoice() something messes up and without throwing any error it just stops execution. Client side then after posting order gets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. generateInvoice() looks like this:

```
module.exports = (order, invoicePath) => {

let invoice = new PDFDocument({ margin: 50 });

invoice.registerFont('PTSans-Regular', path.join(__dirname, '/../public/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf'));
invoice.registerFont('PTSans-Bold', path.join(__dirname, '/../public/fonts/PTSans-Bold.ttf'));

console.log('invoice 1');
generateHeader(invoice, order);
console.log('invoice 2');
generatePersonInformation(invoice, order);
console.log('invoice 3');
generateInvoiceData(invoice, order);
console.log('invoice 4');
generateProductsTable(invoice, order);
console.log('invoice 5');

invoice.end();
console.log('invoice 6');
invoice.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(invoicePath));
console.log('invoice 7');
}
```

The most funny thing is it sometimes stops after logging 'inovoice 3', sometimes 'invoice 5', sometimes 'invoice 2'. Sometimes even the whole invoice gets generated and saved. I checked RAM and CPU and their usage was fine, so its not lack of memory problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using a try catch block around the invoice generating function and catching the error and printing it out.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what i did... nothing. -_(°-°)_-

Comment: i have the same issue altough only on deployed version on fargate. did you find a solution in the mean time?